# How to pause and resume an activity from a customized dialog box? (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I made a customized Dialog box and it has 3 buttons. (The resume, restart, quit).. how would I access the main activity or the actual game to continue when I click the button resume?? Thanks for your help. :))

this is my code for the dialogbox activity:

```
private Tetris mtetris;
Button btResume, btRestart, btQuit;
       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogbox);
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

     btResume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumebt);
     btRestart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartbt);
     btQuit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quitbt);

     btResume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mtetris.mTetrisView.setMode(TetrisTileView.RUNNING);
            mtetris.dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
     btQuit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            }
        });  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Dialog is shown,the activity will be paused(onPause be invoked),and when the dialog is dissmissed,the activity will run into onResume，just resume your game here.

Comment: I will add an onResume method and put the code that will resume the game?? Thanks for your answer :)